# Loading data in WP7 silverlight application and transitions

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, transition

I am making a WP7 Silverlight application and using a ViewModel to store the data and as the datacontext for the pages.

Each PhonePage has its own data and I call the **App.ViewModel.LoadData()** in the Page_Loaded event-handler. There is a ListBox which shows the Data in the ViewModel.

I use the **TurnstileTransition** transition from the Silverlight toolkit from Codeplex. (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291)

**FURTHER CLARIFICATION**
The transition is defined as a resource in App.xaml as:

```
<Style x:Key="TurnstileTransition" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
                <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
                            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
                            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
                            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
                            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
                            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

And every page has the style defined as:

```
Style="{StaticResource TurnstileTransition}"
```

Everything works fine.

However, the data is bound to the Listbox BEFORE the Transition has finished!!

**This looks ugly!**

Can I handle the event at the **END** of the transition (So I **load** the data here and bind it), if so where do i add the eventhandler??

Can I handle the event at the **START** of the transition (So I **clear** the data here), if so where do i add the eventhandler??

Do you suggest some other solution that I must consider?

How can i add an event-handler to the Transition's completed event, what is the name of the transition object??
And transition has 2 types of transitions, can i detect in which type **(Forward or Backward)** of transition happened and completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (within the context of the page you're navigating to)

```
        var transition = TransitionService.GetNavigationInTransition(this); //This being the page with the associated navigation
        transition.EndTransition += transition_EndTransition;

...
        void transition_EndTransition(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = ...;
        }
```

I did this to get a smoother animation because otherwise the DB work I needed to do ruined the fluidity of the transition because it executed too early if I ran it in the OnNavigatedTo 'event'

Comment: That was the exact issue i was referring to ..
thanx, will try it and mark it the answer if correct :)

Answer (score 0):

A Transition has a Completed event which you could use to identify the end of the transition.

There isn't a started event but you could trigger something equivalent to this before you navigate to the page with the transition.

Comment: Hi Matt, please see the above clarification.
Also there is object accessible from code, or i don't know how to get the object? Please suggest a solution.